# Cannot install Jenkins on Linux Ubuntu VM

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, virtual-machine

I am having issues installing Jenkins on my Ubuntu virtual machine. I have looked up the potential solutions to this issue but most of the solutions suggest that the user is using the wrong Java version or does not even have the Java installed. This is not the case in my situation. I have java 17 installed which is one of the Jenkins supported versions:

```
patrikas@test:~$ java --version

openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+7-Ubuntu-120.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+7-Ubuntu-120.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I try to install jenkins, I am getting the following result:

```
patrikas@test:~$ sudo apt-get install jenkins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jenkins
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
60 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/85.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 86.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libapparmor1:amd64 (2.13.3-7ubuntu5.3) ...
Setting up libip4tc2:amd64 (1.8.4-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up mount (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.4) ...
Setting up systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...
Setting up systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...
Selecting previously unselected package jenkins.
(Reading database ... 245378 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../jenkins_2.440.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking jenkins (2.440.1) ...
Setting up motd-news-config (11ubuntu5.8) ...
Setting up tcpdump (4.9.3-4ubuntu0.3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump ...
Setting up systemd-sysv (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...
Setting up apt-utils (2.0.10) ...
Setting up jenkins (2.440.1) ...
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-03-07 11:01:39 EET; 13ms ago
    Process: 15952 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 15952 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 07 11:01:41 test jenkins[16015]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Mar 07 11:01:41 test jenkins[16015]:         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
Mar 07 11:01:41 test jenkins[16015]:         at executable.Main.main(Main.java:351)
Mar 07 11:01:41 test systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 07 11:01:41 test systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 11:01:41 test systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Mar 07 11:01:41 test systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Mar 07 11:01:41 test systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Mar 07 11:01:41 test systemd[1]: Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server...
Mar 07 11:01:42 test jenkins[16059]: Running from: /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: 2024-03-07 09:01:43.147+0000 [id=1]        INFO        winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: 2024-03-07 09:01:43.394+0000 [id=1]        WARNING        o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: 2024-03-07 09:01:43.580+0000 [id=1]        INFO        org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-10.0.18; built: 2023-10-27T01:59:58.245Z; git: 8545fd9bf4cd0d0838f626b405fd4963441546b7; jvm 17.0.10+7-Ubuntu-120.04.1
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: 2024-03-07 09:01:43.642+0000 [id=1]        INFO        org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStop: Stopped Server@4d49af10{STOPPING}[10.0.18,sto=0]
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: 2024-03-07 09:01:43.643+0000 [id=1]        INFO        winstone.Logger#logInternal: Jetty shutdown successfully
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:209)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:496)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at executable.Main.main(Main.java:351)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:304)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.lambda$doStart$0(Server.java:402)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:398)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:205)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         ... 6 more
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:337)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:339)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         ... 21 more
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: 2024-03-07 09:01:43.644+0000 [id=1]        SEVERE        winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:337)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:339)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:304)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.lambda$doStart$0(Server.java:402)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:398)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:205)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]: Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:209)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:496)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test jenkins[16059]:         at executable.Main.main(Main.java:351)
Mar 07 11:01:43 test systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 07 11:01:43 test systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 11:01:43 test systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 installed jenkins package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up apt-transport-https (2.0.10) ...
Setting up python3-problem-report (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.27) ...
Setting up libip6tc2:amd64 (1.8.4-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up distro-info-data (0.43ubuntu1.15) ...
Setting up unzip (6.0-25ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libfwupd2:amd64 (1.7.9-1~20.04.3) ...
Setting up ltrace (0.7.3-6.1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libnetplan0:amd64 (0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.4) ...
Setting up fwupd-signed (1.51.1~20.04.1+1.4-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...
Setting up zabbix-agent2-plugin-postgresql (1:6.4.12-1+ubuntu20.04) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.d/plugins.d/postgresql.conf ...
Setting up libgpgme11:amd64 (1.13.1-7ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up python3-apport (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.27) ...
Setting up netplan.io (0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.4) ...
Setting up dns-root-data (2023112702~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up grub-common (2.04-1ubuntu26.17) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Setting up apparmor (2.13.3-7ubuntu5.3) ...
Reloading AppArmor profiles
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Setting up zabbix-agent2-plugin-mongodb (1:6.4.12-1+ubuntu20.04) ...
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.99.9.12) ...
Setting up python3-debian (0.1.36ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libxtables12:amd64 (1.8.4-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up lynx-common (2.9.0dev.5-1) ...
Setting up sosreport (4.5.6-0ubuntu1~20.04.2) ...
Setting up libfdisk1:amd64 (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.4) ...
Setting up zabbix-agent2 (1:6.4.12-1+ubuntu20.04) ...

Configuration file '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** zabbix_agent2.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? Y
Installing new version of config file /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.d/plugins.d/mqtt.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.d/plugins.d/mysql.conf ...
Setting up uuid-runtime (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.4) ...
Setting up kpartx (0.8.3-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...
Setting up lynx (2.9.0dev.5-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/lynx to provide /usr/bin/www-browser (www-browser) in auto mode
Setting up libfwupdplugin5:amd64 (1.7.9-1~20.04.3) ...
Setting up python3-distro-info (0.23ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up iputils-ping (3:20190709-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fwupd (1.7.9-1~20.04.3) ...
fwupd-offline-update.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
fwupd-refresh.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
fwupd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Setting up iputils-tracepath (3:20190709-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libencode-detect-perl (1.01-5build3) ...
Setting up rsync (3.1.3-8ubuntu0.7) ...
Setting up distro-info (0.23ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up webmin (2.105) ...
Setting up cloud-init (23.4.4-0ubuntu0~20.04.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.alpine.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.centos.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.cos.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.debian.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.fedora.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.freebsd.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.opensuse-leap.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.opensuse-microos.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.opensuse-tumbleweed.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.opensuse.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.photon.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.rhel.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.sle-micro.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.sle_hpc.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.sles.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/chrony.conf.ubuntu.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.alpine.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.debian.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.fedora.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.freebsd.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.opensuse.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.photon.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.rhel.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.sles.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.ubuntu.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntpd.conf.openbsd.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/profile.d/Z99-cloud-locale-test.sh ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/profile.d/Z99-cloudinit-warnings.sh ...
Removing obsolete conffile /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/hook-network-manager ...
Setting up grub2-common (2.04-1ubuntu26.17) ...
Setting up iptables (1.8.4-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up ufw (0.36-6ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up software-properties-common (0.99.9.12) ...
Setting up apport (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.27) ...
apport-autoreport.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Setting up fdisk (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.4) ...
Setting up multipath-tools (0.8.3-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Job failed. See "journalctl -xe" for details.
Removing obsolete conffile /etc/init.d/multipath-tools ...
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:20.04.10.18) ...
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (30~20.04) ...
Removing obsolete conffile /etc/ubuntu-advantage/help_data.yaml ...
Setting up ubuntu-pro-client-l10n (30~20.04) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:20.04.10.18) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.14) ...
Processing triggers for rsyslog (8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-173-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After the installation, I can check the status:

```
patrikas@test:~$ sudo systemctl status jenkins
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-03-07 11:05:36 EET; 1min 21s ago
    Process: 32245 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 32245 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 07 11:05:36 test systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 7.
Mar 07 11:05:36 test systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Mar 07 11:05:36 test systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 07 11:05:36 test systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 11:05:36 test systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
```

I would appreciate any clarifications regarding this

Comment: The relevant bits in there are `Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080` `Address already in use`. Either configure it to use a different port or find whatever is listening there and (re)move that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have tried to replace the 8080 port with some other port in the ```/etc/defaults/jenkins```. After updating the configuration, I cannot seem to be able to restart the Jenkins service to ensure the new port is used.  When I try to restart jenkins service:
```Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.```